# AngularJS custom error directive not detecting data changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I am writing a custom angular directive so that I can use it across many pages on a site to give a similar feel of errors to users.  To do this, I have created the directive shown below.

```
angular.module('ErrorMessages', []);

angular.module('ErrorMessages').directive('errorMessage', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/Directives/ErrorDirective/Error.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        multiElement: true,
        scope: {
            resultData: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            alert('result data is: ' + attrs.resultData);
            scope.$watch(attrs.resultData, function (value) {
                alert(value);
                if (value == undefined || value.length == 0) {
                    alert('Dont show error');
                        scope.ShowError = false;
                } else {
                    alert('show error');
                        scope.ShowError = true;
                        scope.Messages = value;
                    }
                });
            }
    }
});
```

Current Template is here.

```
<div style="color: red;" ng-show="ShowError">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Error</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12 error">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="message in Messages">{{message}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then mark it up on the html page as such.

```
<error-Message result-data="Errors"></error-Message>
```

What I want to be able to do is set the Errors variable on the controller and have the error show or hide.

```
$scope.Errors = [];
$scope.Errors.push('error text');
```

But when I do this, it doesn't appear that the watch is being triggered.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE **`$watchCollection`**:

```
     ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶w̶a̶t̶c̶h̶(̶a̶t̶t̶r̶s̶.̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶D̶a̶t̶a̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶)̶ ̶{̶ 
     scope.$watchCollection(attrs.resultData, function (value) {
```

or USE **deep $watch**:

```
    scope.$watch(attrs.resultData, function (value) {
        alert(value);
        if (value == undefined || value.length == 0) {
            alert('Dont show error');
                scope.ShowError = false;
        } else {
            alert('show error');
                scope.ShowError = true;
                scope.Messages = value;
            }
        ̶}̶)̶;̶
        //USE DEEP WATCH
        }, true);
```

Dirty checking can be done with three strategies: By reference, by collection contents, and by value. The strategies differ in the kinds of changes they detect, and in their performance characteristics.

[image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$watch` Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$watch` Performance Considerations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-performance-considerations)